# rebase branch is direct ancestor, yet rebase fails

Tags: git, git-merge, git-rebase

I encountered today a situation where a rebase failed even though the target branch is a direct ancestor of the branch I am trying to rebase.

I am currently in branch `changes-2021` and trying to rebase onto `master`:

```
$ git merge-base changes-2021 master
e335d3ebd223ad21cd53b2cf3f16876f01fc1aef
$ git show e335d3ebd223ad21cd53b2cf3f16876f01fc1aef
commit e335d3ebd223ad21cd53b2cf3f16876f01fc1aef (origin/master, origin/HEAD, master)
...
(so master is a direct ancestor)
$ git rebase master
... 
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in frontend/src/style.scss
error: Failed to merge in the changes
...
```

How is that possible? I was expecting the rebase to be entirely uneventful like every other time I've encountered a similar situation in the past. The only difference this time is that the branch I am trying to rebase onto is pointing to a rather old commit (~ 5 months ago) but it's still a direct ancestor of the current branch.

Comment: Nothing "failed". It's just a merge "conflict" in one little file. Perfectly normal when rebasing. Resolve it and move on.

Comment: I wonder why you would rebase on top of a revision that is a direct ancestor to your branch. In simple terms (and it's not so simple, anyway), it's basically a no-op. You would apply the same revisions that make up `e335d3ebd223a..HEAD` on top of `e335d3ebd223a` so you would get the same history/content. What is the _purpose_ of this?

Comment: _then_, we have the issue of _why_ a conflict is there in the first place? I would _assume_ that you have merges in the range `e335d3ebd223a..HEAD` (that `git rebase` by default does not rebase) and that have included changes that, because they are missing in _this_ rebase, produce a conflict.

Comment: @eftshift0 the purpose is because I want the changes to appear on the master branch (currently they reside on a feature branch).

Comment: @matt my mental model was that conflicts cannot possibly arise if the branch you are rebasing onto is a direct ancestor of your branch. That's why I asked this question.

Comment: yeah.... but you get _nothing_ out of that rebase (except for trouble, as you can see). What are the next steps you follow to get stuff in master?

Comment: But you didn't ask _that_. You asked about "fails", which it didn't. Please say what you mean.

Comment: _and_ I explained _why_ it can in fact happen. Read my comment about it.

Comment: If you know what a rebase / cherry pick is, and you know what merge logic is, it's actually pretty obvious. Merge conflicts are _very_ common when doing rebase / cherry pick / revert, because they are "strange" things to do.

Comment: @eftshift0 after I rebase the feature branch onto master, I switch to master and do a merge of the master branch with the feature branch which is, at that point, always uneventful fast-forward. I am quite sure this is the standard workflow.

Comment: ah.... no. The _standard workflow_ (if you mean _the workflow with as little work as possible_) for your scenario would be to just switch to master and merge the feature branch because that will produce a fast-forward (because master is on an ancestor of the feature branch, so no need to rebase). A rebase would be needed if master had moved and it were placed on a revision that is _not_ an ancestor of the feature branch... but that is _not_ your scenario.

Comment: @eftshift0 ok, that cleared up everything.

Comment: But now I am a little bit curious. This feature branch has merges _after_ `master`? Or it's a straight line from `master`? If it's a straight line from master, there _should_ be no conflicts.... actually, I would be extremely surprised if there were conflicts if it's a straight line.

Comment: @eftshift0 if it's linear, not only should there not be conflicts, it would have said "already up to date" when attempting to rebase.

Comment: So, to summarize all of these comments, one of the following is true: 1.) `changes-2021` has a new merge on the branch after `master` and this merge had to resolve conflicts when it was created. or 2.) You weren't actually on `changes-2021` like you thought you were. Assuming #1 is the case, by rebasing you are attempting to "linearize" that merge commit and will have to re-resolve the conflict you already previously resolved in the merge commit you are "popping".

Comment: @TTT #1 is the case. I had created a sub-feature branch which I merged into the feature branch so even though the master branch was a direct ancestor the path from the master branch to the tip of the feature branch was not entirely linear. So, IIUC, it seems that to see "already up to date" when attempting to rebase it is not sufficient that the master branch is a direct ancestor, it is also necessary that the entire feature branch is linear.

Comment: @eftshift0 see my reply to TTT

Comment: Well.... I think you have all relevant information about why you are facing the _unexpected_ conflict at hand: rebase does _not_ rebase merges by default. If there is a change introduced in a merge (to solve a conflict or not, it can be done either way), you would miss it... from that point on, a conflict might happen if you have other revisions that are rebased that are related to that piece of code that was touched in the original (and un-rebased) merged revision.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When doing a regular rebase, in the case where the target branch is a direct ancestor of the branch you wish to rebase, one of two things should happen:

1. If your history is linear after the target branch, you will receive a message similar to, "Branch is up to date." This is because a rebase with the default options would have no effect, so it doesn't even attempt it.
2. If your history is *not* linear after the target branch, meaning there is at least one new merge commit, it will attempt to replay all of the commits not reachable by the target *except* for the merge commits.

Since the rebase was attempted, we know you are in situation #2 (and this was also confirmed in the comments). As for why there are conflicts, this is simply the same reason any merge might have conflicts. Possibly one of the merge commits on your branch (later than the target branch) had a conflict when it was originally created, so, when the commits on either side of that merge are attempted to be rewritten linearly, the same conflict(s) will occur again. Note that since the commits are replayed one by one in a rebase, the likelihood of conflicts in this case is actually higher than if you elected to rewrite the merge commits too, by using the `--rebase-merges` option.